# Efficiently Combing data based on date and name in excel

Tags: excel

I am interested in matching data together in excel.The following is example data.

```
Date|Name|Size
----|----|----
6/7 |dan |23
6/7 |reg |24
6/8 |carl|25
6/8 |reg |12
6/9 |dan |23

Date|Name|Size
----|----|----
6/7 |dan |27
6/7 |reg |22
6/8 |reg |21
6/8 |carl|19
6/8 |alf |16
6/9 |dan |12
```

and I want an output table like the following where date and name are matched together. Some dates and some names may only be in one table in that case the other size column should be left blank.

```
Date|Name|Size|Size
----|----|----|---
6/7 |dan |23  |27
6/7 |reg |24  |22
6/8 |carl|25  |19
6/8 |reg |12  |21
6/8 |alf |16  |
6/9 |dan |23  |2
```

Comment: Show  us what you have tried, and where you have run into problems. To better understand how this forum works, please start by taking the [2-minute tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First start by:

- Copy the first 2 columns of table1 to a new sheet3
- Copy the first 2 columns of table2 under it in sheet3
- Select all in sheet3 and Remove Duplicates

You will have the first 2 columns of the new Data in sheet3

```
 A     B      C      D
Date   Name   Size   Size

6/7    dan     23     27
6/7    reg     24     22
6/8    carl    25     19
6/8    reg     12     21
6/9    dan     23     12
6/8    alf            16
```

Under first size in C2:    `=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$6,MATCH($A2&$B2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6&Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6,0)),"")`

Under second size in D2:    `=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$7,MATCH($A2&$B2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$7&Sheet2!$B$2:$B$7,0)),"")`

Array Formula press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> together instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>
and drag the formulas down in the column
Remember to change A2:A6, B2:B6 for each sheet to the last row of your Data and keep the $ for fixed references